# Swift: Prevent extra escape sequences in JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I posted earlier about a related problem, but I thought I'd make a new post.

I am making a post request from IOS to a app service that returns a JSON. The JSON returned is formatted like this:

`"{\"raw\":\"schedule for John in New York on Monday\",\"location\":\"new york\",\"date\":\"6/26/2017 12:00:00 AM\",\"name\":\"john\",\"errorResponse\":null,\"stripTest\":\" for john in new york on monday \"}"`

However, when I print String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) where data is the request's return value, I get:

`Optional("\"{\\"raw\\":\\"Schedule for John in New York on Monday\\",\\"location\\":\\"new york\\",\\"date\\":\\"6/26/2017 12:00:00 AM\\",\\"name\\":\\"john\\",\\"errorResponse\\":null,\\"stripTest\\":\\" for john in new york on monday \\"}\"")'

I'm assuming this is happening when I convert "data" to a string. Is there any way to avoid this?

The resultant string is useless as I can't convert it to a dictionary to access the data. I've tried converting directly from Data to dictionary, but this doesn't seem to work either (the resultant dictionary has 0 key/value pairs).

Maybe the extra characters are being added as soon as the app stores the return value?

```
let json: [String: String] = ["raw": self.result]
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

var postRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "blahblah.com/")!)
postRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
postRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
postRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

//insert JSON data to the new request
postRequest.httpBody = jsonData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: postRequest) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "NoData")
        return
    }

    let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(jsonString)

    let jsonData = jsonString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

    if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject]

}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: You should be able to convert straight from the data, I would suggest you focus on trying to fix that, rather than trying to convert to a string to then convert. Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427500/swift-3-0-data-to-json-string-any

Comment: Yes, this is the first thing that I tried (one of probably 20 other solutions). First, I had to use "options: .allowFragments" because of how my JSON is formatted. Regardless, this gave me an empty dictionary. I think it's because of extra escape sequences in "data". If I explicitly type out the JSON instead of using the request's return value, everything works fine.